# Неоднократный вызов метода для объекта

Tags: java

Надеюсь простая задача. Сломал голову. Есть допустим класс Class. У него есть местод void add (int a, double b). Параметр класса массив double. При каждом обращении к add объектом Class массив заполняется а и b. Как мне организовать метод add, чтобы объект класса Class обращался к нему сколько надо раз в одну строку.
Многократно это не проблема. я сделал.
эскизный пример

```
public class Сlass {

    private double[] array=new double[1000];
    private int counter;

    public double[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    void clear(){
        counter=0;
        array=new double[1000];
    }

    public void add(int a, double b){

    }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
Class class=new Class();
class.add(a,b).add(a,b)... и тд сколько надо
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вызывать цепочку методов, нужно из метода возвращать сам объект

Попробуйте:

```
public Сlass add(int a, double b){
    // Тут логика добавления

    // Возвращаем себя же
    return this;
}
```